# Codeigniter, Multiple queries from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter

Try to get my controller return the data from two queries, and then display them to view. The first query results to one record, the Exercise, and the second query results to many records, the Questions.

My view does not load either the paragraphs of the exercise, or the questions of the exercise.

Exercise Controller:

```
public function exquestdisplay()
{
  $this->load->model('Exercise_model');

  $data['exquest'] = $this->Exercise_model->get_ex_quest();

  $this->load->view('readeralter/header');
  $this->load->view('readeralter/menu_2');
  $this->load->view('readeralter/dashboard_view');
  $this->load->view('readeralter/play_quiz', $data);
  $this->load->view('readeralter/footer');
}
```

Exercise Model:

```
function get_ex_quest(){
//get exercise's paragraphs
$this->db->select("exercise_id, exercise_difficulty, exercise_title, exercise_par1, exercise_par2, exercise_par3, exercise_par4, exercise_par5, exercise_par6");
$this->db->from("exercises");
$this->db->where("exercise_id","1");

$query1 = $this->db->get();

//get exercise's questions
$this->db->select("question_id, question_title, question_choice1, question_choice2, question_choice3, question_answer");
$this->db->from("questions");
$this->db->where("question_exercise_id","1");

$query2 = $this->db->get();

if ($query1->num_rows() < 1 && $query2->num_rows() < 1) {
          echo "There is no data in the database";
          exit();
        }
  elseif($query1->num_rows() == 1 && $query2->num_rows() < 1){
          echo "There is no data in the database";
          exit();
        }
      else {
        $paragraphs = $query1->row();
        $questions = $query2->result();
        return array($paragraphs, $questions);
      }
```

}

Exercise View:

```
<p><b><?=$row->exercise_id?>.<?=$row->exercise_difficulty?>.<?=$row->exercise_title?></b></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par1?></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par2?></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par3?></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par4?></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par5?></p>
<p><?=$row->exercise_par6?></p>

<?php } ?>

<?php foreach($exquest['questions'] as $row) { ?>

    <?php $ans_array = array($row->question_choice1, $row->question_choice2, $row->question_choice3, $row->question_answer);?>

    <p><b><?=$row->question_id?>.<?=$row->question_title?></b></p>

    <input type="radio" name="ex_id<?=$row->question_id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?> &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="ex_id<?=$row->question_id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?> &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="ex_id<?=$row->question_id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?> &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="ex_id<?=$row->question_id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems that I see, which once fixed should help:

The select method accepts a comma delimited string of field names, not what appears to be array elements.

So, instead of doing this:

```
$this->db->select('a','b','c');
```

You should be doing this:

```
$this->db->select('a, b, c');
```

Then the where method is also not used correctly. It should accept two parameters.

So where your usage is like this:

```
$this->db->where('a = 1');
```

You should simply be doing this:

```
$this->db->where('a', 1);
```

You may have other problems, but another I see is that in your view your data should be available as query objects `$exquest['paragraphs']` and `$exquest['questions']`, but these are not immediately usable, because you never apply `->result()` or `->row()`. Normally, when you do a query, you will want to check if there are results, so back in your model, do something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
    // you can use the result
    $results = $query->result();
}
```

Or if you were only expecting a single row:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if( $query->num_rows() == 1 ){
    // you can use the result
    $row = $query->row();
}
```

This information should help you get things working.

Comment: Changed the Model according to your comment but nothing happened. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this in your model :

```
$query1 = $this->db->select('...')->from('...')->where('...')->get();
$query2 = $this->db->select('...')->from('...')->where('...')->get();
```